# Command for splitting a List of Lists into a List of the First Element of Each List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im trying to create 2 lists form a list of lists, the following code is a working easy example, but it makes sense to think there is a command that can be used instead of creating the for loop for splitting.

```
def add_five(x):
    return x,x + 5
result1=[]
result2=[]
nums = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
result = list(map(add_five, nums))
print(result)
for n in range(len(result)):
    result1.append(result[n][0])
    result2.append(result[n][1])
print(result1,result2)
```

The list of lists is:

```
[(11, 16), (22, 27), (33, 38), (44, 49), (55, 60)]
result1=[11, 22, 33, 44, 55] 
result2=[16, 27, 38, 49, 60]
```

Is there a command that can help aviod using the for loop?

Comment: Look into the builtin function `zip`, which is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to extract the *n*th element of each `tuple`:

```
L = [(11, 16), (22, 27), (33, 38), (44, 49), (55, 60)]

result1 = [i[0] for i in L]
result2 = [i[1] for i in L]
```

Functionally, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for the equivalent:

```
from operator import itemgetter

result1 = list(map(itemgetter(0), L))
result2 = list(map(itemgetter(1), L))
```

If you *don't* know the size of your tuples in advance, the recommended solution is `zip`, which will output a list of tuples, each tuple representing a tuple index:

```
results = list(zip(*L))

[(11, 22, 33, 44, 55), (16, 27, 38, 49, 60)]
```

You can even use sequence unpacking here without forming the full list:

```
result1, result2 = zip(*L)
```